# Prefix relative paths for cdn with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

I have a simple website with relative references to css files and javascript files in the header. Is there a way to expand these to absolute url's and prefix them with "cdn." automatically on page load?

Here is part of my current head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/the-tooltip.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/utf8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/sha1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/validatious.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What i need in the end is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.mydomain.com/css/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.mydomain.com/css/the-tooltip.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.mydomain.com/js/utf8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.mydomain.com/js/sha1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.mydomain.com/js/validatious.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add prefix to all script elements:

```
function appendPrefix(prefix) {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
      links =  document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
      foreach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  foreach.call(scripts, function (s) {
    if (s.src && (/(http|https)/).test(s.src)) {
       s.src = prefix + s.src;
    }
  });
  foreach.call(links, function (l) {
    if (s.src && (/(http|https)/).test(l.href)) {
       l.href = prefix + l.href;
    }
  });
}

appendPrefix('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

The script is pure JavaScript and works for both `script` and `link` tags. It will append the prefix only to those `link` and `script` tags which does not start with `http://`.

Comment: Looks good. Can i somehow ensure it runs before the browser tries to fetch the actual files?

Comment: You cant run it before the loading is started. The loading begins when the DOM elements are in the DOM tree, you cant replace element's `href` and `src` attributes before they are in the DOM tree.

Answer (score -1):

You can do redirect requests `/css/*` or `/js/*` to `cdn.example.com/css/*` or `cdn.example.com/js/*` in configuration files of web server (e.g, .htaccess for Apache-server) and browser get necessary files. This solution will make the load on your web server (not as much as send css or js files), so it is best to write path to cdn manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is another big issue other than load. This actually forces the users to connect to my server again and again, and then the cdn, instead of requesting the resource directly from the cdn in the first place. No point of a cdn with this solution unfortunately.

Comment: I understand, but there is no other automated solutions. Changes on client side (javascript) does not solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It appears like JS isn't the best solution. I solved the problem using PHP on the serverside instead. I defined a global $prefix variable and appended that to a dynamically generated hostname and path to get the absolute URL and still maintain portability of the script.

Comment: The issue here is that nowhere in the question does it state that this is a server-side page. This would not be possible on any sort of hosting without PHP support.